# Color coding Parallel Coordinates

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I have already a code parallel coordinates graph, everything works fine. Now i'm trying to use colors to color-code the parallel coordinates visualization, but something is wrong. In dataset (http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine/wine.data) i've got different names of wine species (1st column is class identifier (1-3)), but in graph draws only one color. Could anybody help me?

Graph :

[image]

```
enter code here
    // CREATE A COLOR SCALE
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(['1','2','3'])
  .range(['red','blue','green'])

d3.csv("wine.csv", function(error, wine) {

  // Extract the list of dimensions and create a scale for each.
  x.domain(dimensions = d3.keys(wine[0]).filter(function(d) {
    return d != "name" && (y[d] = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain(d3.extent(wine, function(p) { return +p[d]; }))
        .range([h, 0]));
  }));

  // Add grey background lines for context.
  background = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "background")
    .selectAll("path")
      .data(wine)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path);

  // USE THE COLOR SCALE TO SET THE STROKE BASED ON THE DATA
  foreground = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "foreground")
    .selectAll("path")
      .data(wine)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
      .attr("stroke", function(d) {
        var species = d.name.slice(0,d.name.indexOf(' '));
        return color(species);
      })
```

Comment: what are the values for d.name ?

Comment: If this is a binomial nomenclature, you're getting only the Genus with `var species`. If you are dealing with binomial names, like "Vitis vinifera", the best idea is joining the Genus and the specific epithet together, using this: str = str.replace(/\s/g, ''); It will turn "Vitis vinifera" into "Vitisvinifera".

Comment: I named as "name" 1st column of dataset (http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine/wine.data) values are 1,2,3

Comment: But the first column is just a number. In that case, you don't need the `slice`.

Comment: species are named as 1, 2 and 3

Comment: So, just use `.attr("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });`

Comment: everything works fine, thanks

Comment: Put this in the answer if there is any benefits for you :)

Comment: Not for me, but for SO: SO is a knowledge database, so it's always good to have a valid question/answer match. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you already have your ordinal scale for the colors with the `domain` and `range` defined, you only need to color your lines according to `d.name`:

```
.attr("stroke", function(d) {
    return color(d.name);
  });
```